airflow : Task exited with return code -9
I'm attempting to run a Python code for OCR using EasyOCR within an Airflow environment in a Docker setup, but I encountered the following error: {local_task_job_runner.py:234} INFO - Task exited with return code -9
Upon investigation, it appears to be an out of memory error. My inquiry is: How can I allocate more memory to the Airflow worker?
